# Shuffle a list in a future builder in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 1000+ documents in "posts" collection in Firestore. I want to shuffle them and show to users. How to do it?

Below is my try. But, I think, It's not good because all the document store in list `variable`.

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: _getList(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
      } else {
        List list = snapshot.data!;
        list.shuffle(); // shuffle the list
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: list.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(list[index]),
            );
          },
        );
      }
    } else {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
  },
);
```

Comment: It's better to shuffle the list inside the `_getList` function, not inside the UI.

Comment: That method is ok? All documents get to one variable?

Comment: everytime you call the `_getList` function, the order would be completely different from the last time. If you want to shuffle the list just once and then for next times get the same shuffled list, you have to cache it somewhere and return the cached value.